# Using Rails 3, Unicorn & Nginx, How do I get access to the host for a subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, unicorn

My rails app toggles functionality based on the subdomain e.g. blah1.mysite.com & blah2.mysite.com

I want to access the subdomain in my rails controller by using request.host but the host is always mysite_qa for every subdomain I try in the browser.  How do I fix this?

I think this is an issue with my nginx config and I'm an nginx noob so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the sites-available record in nginx:

```
upstream mysite_qa {
        ip_hash;                  # If you enable the second one and don't make sessions common
        server localhost:9002;
}

server {
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        listen 80;
        #listen 443 ssl;          # If you end up enabling SSL
        server_name qa.mysite.com;
        server_name blah1.mysite.com;
        server_name blah2.mysite.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://mysite_qa;
                allow all;
        }
        location /nginx_status {
                stub_status on;
                access_log   off;
                allow 10.8.0.0/24;
                allow 172.16.0.0/16;
                deny all;
        }

}
```

Here is my unicorn file:

```
worker_processes 4

APP_PATH = "/var/www/qa.mysite.com"
working_directory APP_PATH

stderr_path APP_PATH + "/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path APP_PATH + "/log/unicorn.stderr.log"

pid APP_PATH + "/tmp/pid/unicorn.pid"

listen 9002, :tcp_nopush => true

# nuke workers after 30 seconds instead of 60 seconds (the default)
timeout 30

preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # the following is highly recomended for Rails + "preload_app true"
  # as there's no need for the master process to hold a connection
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1

nginx version: nginx/1.1.19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx can set a header containing the original hostname, then your application can read that header:

http://www.simplicidade.org/notes/archives/2011/02/nginx_proxy_host_header.html

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://mysite_qa;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            allow all;
    }
```